# Should custom page layouts be displayed in the More Options menu?

Tags: page-layout

I'm working on a SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site that was upgraded from 2007.  I've noticed that when I go to Site Actions -> More Options, I can create lists, sites, pages, etc.  I see my custom Site Templates in this list, but I don't see my custom Page Layouts.

My question is, should I see my custom page layouts in this area?

The page layouts seem to be working great in every other way:  If I uninstall silverlight, and go to the create page:  http://siteurl/_Layouts/CreatePage.aspx, I see the page layouts.  And I can change the page layout just fine after creating a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just looked at a Publishing Site that I just created and also noticed that my new layout was not showing.  So what I did is clicked on the icon Publishing Page.  Once I gave the page a title and hit create you should see your page listed.  Hope this helps.

Akalicious

Comment: Akalicious! Thanks buddy.  Yeah it seems like that's the missing step to get the page layout options.  Think we'll communicate to our content owners to create page and then just select the page layout when creating a new publishing page in 2010.